# Make one server use another server to get access to the web

Tags: proxy, yum

I have a following question. I have two servers running CentOS 6.2. Let's name them A and B.

Our network is constructed in such a way, that server A has access to the internet via a proxy. It can access the proxy. However, server B may access only server A in any way possible, but not the proxy directly. Therefore, is there a way to configure both servers so that server B could use server A in order to retrieve from the internet the required packages.

More specifically, server A uses cntlm to access the proxy (since the proxy is in Windows Domain). I need to configure YUM at server B to be able to download from remote repositories, and it should be done via server A, since it cannot access directly the proxy in Windows Domain itself. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer to the problem. By default cntlm is run in such a way, that it allows only local processes to connect.

In order to make it serve as the normal proxy, you have to make it gateway. Add the next line to cntlm.conf:

```
Gateway yes
```

By default this line is connected. However, be careful, because here you may have the following problem:

- Since it's now open, everyone can use it. So you should add to cntlm.conf specific ACL list, that allows only some addresses, but denies everything else.
- Even if you make it as gateway, your firewall may still block it. Therefore you should setup firewall, so it would not block the internal server (but it also may deny all other addresses).
- In config, all the Listen commands before Gateway command are considered still to be local and will not respond to the outer world. Make sure you put your Listen command AFTER the Gateway command.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to set up another proxy.

ServerA will proxy requests for ServerB

ServerB's traffic must go through ServerA (somehow).

This article explains it: http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/TransparentProxy.html#ss6.1